# how to bind datetime value with flip-countdown vue js in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to bind datetime with the [`flip-countdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-flip-countdown) component so that it reads the date and time to start displaying and counting down the time.

My issue is that it can't read the time, or the datetime is not bound with the `flip-countdown` component.

The template:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-4" dir="ltr">          
                <flip-countdown v-bind:deadline="this.time|created_at" :showDays="false"></flip-countdown>
            </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

The script:

```
 import FlipCountdown from 'vue2-flip-countdown'
 export default {
        components: { FlipCountdown },
        name: "TimeEntry",

        data() {
            return {
                
                time: '',
               
            }
        },
  methods: {
       getTime(){
                axios.get('/api/last_time')
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        console.log(data.time);
                        // this.times = data.times.data;
                        this.time = data.time;
                    })
            }
    },
   created() {
            
            this.getTime();
            
        }
```

API Route:

```
Route::get('/last_time', function (){
    $tim = \App\TimeEntry::latest()->where('time_end', null)->first()->created_at;
    $time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($tim)->addHour(7);

    return response()->json(['time'=>$time]);
});
```

Filter:

```
Vue.filter('created_at', function(time_end){
    return moment(time_end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
});
```

I tried to display the value of: `this.time|created_at` in `<p>{{ this.time|created_at }} </p>`, and the output was: `2020-07-23 18:58:07`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue filters are intended to be used in string interpolation, not bindings.

One solution is to use a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that returns the `time` formatted:

```html
<template>
  <flip-countdown :deadline="formattedTime" :showDays="false"></flip-countdown>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    formattedTime() {
      return moment(this.time).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your way and it bound the datetime but still there is a problem, I went to vue tab in google chrome's inspector and saw the value of the prob : deadline:"2020-07-24 23:08:58"
but still there's a problem, in vue inspector tab the values in the computed : days:0
hours:0
minutes:0
seconds:0
In order for for the flip-down to work , computed  days , hours , minutes , seconds must have values from the prob: deadline.
I couldn't understand why it is not working.
 @tony19

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Can you share a reproduction in Codesandbox?

Comment: It might be that you're setting `this.time` to the current time (or past time), in which case the countdown would be done immediately. `this.time` must be set to a *future* time, e.g., 30 seconds into the future: `this.time = moment().add(30, "s").valueOf()`

Comment: I'm using Carbon to add 7 hours to the created_at time retrieved from database so, the value of the time returned is the time when the record is created + 7 hours. The time is in the future not the current time. $time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($tim)->addHour(7);